# open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) Android Camera App

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, android-camerax, android-storage

I've created an app takes photos and after it takes, crops the image within specific borders and passes that photo to preview activity and that preview activity uploads the cropped photo to server but here's the problem I'm getting this "no such file or directory" problem.

I've debugged the code and check my device storage if the images are stored where I wanted to and answer is yes, images are successfully stored in my devices storage even the cropped images, here's the logcats image for this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IKm0.png)  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4Fp9.png), and here's my code p.s.I've added every permission to my manifest file

preview activity :

```
class CameraPreviewActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val viewModel: CameraPreviewViewModel by viewModels()
    private val chartViewModel: ChartActivityViewModel by viewModels()
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityPreviewBinding
    private lateinit var imagePath: String // Declare a variable to store the image path


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityPreviewBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        initializeView()
        observeLiveDataResponse()
        hideSystemNavigationBars()
        binding.buttonUpload.performClick()
        binding.buttonUpload.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    }

    private fun hideSystemNavigationBars() {
        val windowInsetsController =
            ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(window.decorView) ?: return
        windowInsetsController.systemBarsBehavior =
            WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
        windowInsetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
    }

    private fun observeLiveDataResponse() {
        viewModel.response.observe(this) { response ->
            response?.let {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Uploaded successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                viewModel.uploadFileName(response.FileName)
            } ?: run {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                startActivity(Intent(this, CameraActivity::class.java))
            }
            binding.layoutLoading.visibility = View.GONE
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please wait for Sensor Respond.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            binding.respondBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }

        viewModel.fileNameResponse.observe(this){response ->
            response?.let {
                ChartActivity.addSensorItem(SensorItem(it.DetectedSensor?:"",true))
                startActivity(Intent(this, ChartActivity::class.java))
                finish()
            } ?: run {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                startActivity(Intent(this, CameraActivity::class.java))
            }
        }

        chartViewModel.sensorResponse.observe(this) { response ->
            response?.let {

            } ?: run {

            }
        }
    }

    private fun initializeView() {
        val photoUri = intent.getParcelableExtra<Uri>("photoUri")
        imagePath = photoUri?.path ?: ""
        Glide.with(this@CameraPreviewActivity).load(photoUri).into(binding.imageView)

        binding.buttonBack.setOnClickListener {
            finish()
        }
        binding.buttonUpload.setOnClickListener {
            binding.layoutLoading.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            Log.e("demo", imagePath)
            viewModel.uploadImage(File(imagePath))
        }
    }

    companion object {
        var path: String? = null
    }

}
```

this is the upload functions for image and file name:

```
suspend fun uploadImage(file: File): ApiResponse? {
        return try {
            val response = api.uploadImage(
                files = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(
                    "files",
                    file.name,
                    file.asRequestBody(),
                )
            )
            response
        }catch (e: Exception){
            e.printStackTrace()
            null
        }
    }

    suspend fun  uploadFileName(fileName: String?): FileNameResponse?{
        return try {
            val response = api.uploadFileName(fileNameRequest = FileNameRequest(fileName))
            response
        }catch (e:Exception){
            e.printStackTrace()
            null
        }
    }
```

and this is my preview view model code:

```
class CameraPreviewViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: CameraRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _response = MutableLiveData<ApiResponse>()
    val response: LiveData<ApiResponse> = _response


    private val _fileNameResponse = MutableLiveData<FileNameResponse>()
    val fileNameResponse: LiveData<FileNameResponse> = _fileNameResponse


    fun uploadImage(file: File) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _response.postValue(repository.uploadImage(file))
        }
    }

    fun uploadFileName(fileName: String?) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _fileNameResponse.postValue(repository.uploadFileName(fileName))
        }
    }
}
```

thanks in advance I couldn't figure it out what's causing the problem

Comment: "that preview activity uploads the cropped photo to server but here's the problem I'm getting this "no such file or directory" problem" -- your question does not show any code related to this activity or its upload work, nor the full stack trace.

Comment: i've edited the question you can see preview activities code

Comment: You should only post code that tries to upload a file. If the file is there -as you told us- you do not need to show how you created the file. Please remove all irrelevant code.

Comment: sorry for my amateur mistake, i thought maybe the main problem is how i save these image files i'll post the code in a minute like you told me